# SSL HTTPs secured website

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ssl, https

i am working on java springs website where we need to make it secured i mean from http to https and i have installed SSL. when i try opening https://abc.in then it works fine but when i try opening https:/abc.in/abcadmin then it will show code behind also i tested in some website for correct installation then it showed it has installed correct.

tried so far: installed and reinstalled SSL and changed httpd.conf files and did trial and error restarting tomcat server

Comment: Please provide details on configuration: have you secured Tomcat or secured Apache HTTP Server which proxies requests to Tomcat...

Comment: https:/abc.in/abcadmin is not a syntactically correct URL :-)

Comment: Francois can you pls check this https://abd.in/abcadmin

Comment: Cebence i have secured apache HTTP server